# Reading floating point numbers from file in Matlab

Tags: file, matlab

I have a textfile that looks like

```
0.47814941 0.47802734 0.47802734 0.47802734 0.47827148 0.47814941
0.47802734 0.47802734 0.47802734 0.47802734 0.47827148 0.47802734
0.47827148 0.47814941 0.47802734 0.47802734 0.47814941 0.47814941
```

The problem is that at some line there are only 5 numbers and at other lines 6. Therefore working with textscan is difficult. I prefer to one large output vector with all the numbers starting the top row from left to right, then the next row etcetera. I think there is no predifined function available but any help is appreciated

Summarized: I try to obtain one output vector containing all numbers read from left to right, top to bottom

Comment: Where is the problem using `textscan`?

Comment: Do you want the output as a single vector or not? You question is unclear on this as you talk about rows as well as numbers going left to right.

Comment: The problem with textscan is that some rows have 5 numbers and others 6. Thus textscan will give a 6th vector with a lot of zeros. Yes, I want the output as a single vector starting with the number at first row, first column, then first row, second column, frst row, third column... etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

```
str = 'Let try to found this number 1001 and the other one 120.29284832';
dum=regexp(str,'\d+.\d+','match');
```

Maybe you'll need to work with the regexp for your case.

Because if the string is :

```
str = 'Digit number like this .2020';
```

The `dum` variable only contain `2020` and not `.2020`.